# Meteor.js + Mongo: How can I write to my Mongo collection from an external process?

Tags: django, mongodb, meteor, upsert

I have a Meteor app running on Heroku with a Mongo database addon through Compose (previously MongoHQ).

I would like to insert documents into this database from an entirely different app (Python/Django, not Meteor).  So I installed `pymongo` into my Django app, got the connection URI for mongodb configured correctly, and so forth.

However, when I try to call the following line:

```
my_dict_collection.update({'id': my_dict['id']}, my_dict, upsert=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
OperationFailure: not authorized for upsert on meteor.my_dict_collection
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get past it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do upsert ops in meteor, you should be able to do them in any other app too.

Did you configure it as follows?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME' : 'my_database',
        'HOST' : 'database_host',
        'PORT' : 'database_port',
        'USER' : 'database_user',
        'PASSWORD' : 'database_password',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'slave_okay' : True,
            'tz_aware' : True,
            'network_timeout' : 42,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

[See documentation here.](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html#configuration)

Using the credentials you get from:

```
heroku config:get MONGO_URL
```

It should give you a mongodb url in the format of:

```
mongodb://database_user:database_password@database_host:database_port/database_name
```

The url above may have a comma-separated list of alternative hostnames. I am not sure if django-mongodb supports that, so you may have to use only one them.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also not using django-mongodb.  I'm using the correct mongodb URI, which I got from heroku config as you described.  I'm not configuring the Mongo database connection in `settings.py`, though -- rather, I'm just passing the full URI to the `pymongo.MongoClient()`. Is it possible to configure two databases in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes you can. The above example will designate that database as "default". You can add more databases by any name.

Comment: It looks like django-mongodb-engine requires me to use a fork of Django.  I'd rather just stick to standard Django.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812274/django-1-7-configure-app-that-has-default-postgresql-db-to-also-use-secondary

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just create a Meteor.method in your app and then call that using a ddp client. See http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients#Python